# How to get the guide to spawn in his room?

Tags: terraria

I have built this simple room:

[image]

I've flagged it for the guide to come, but he isn't coming. Last I checked, he was stuck on the other side of the map. What do I have to do to get him to live in this room?

Comment: You can always get him killed. I think it respawns him in the home when that happens.

Comment: There is a bug in 1.1.2 that NPCs don't use wooden platforms when pathfinding, so your guide will not be able to scale that ladder even if you get him to come home. Actually, even without the bug he can only jump 3 or 4 blocks up, so the rungs are too widely spaced.

Comment: Oh OK. But after I restarted the game, he did appear in the house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initially create a house and the guide cannot reasonably get in there (such as in your screenshot), you can either:

- Move several screens-width away from your house in any direction
- Exit and reload the map

As long as its valid housing and you're able to set the NPC flag, either of the above will teleport them inside your house.